# RegExp: Ignore all links starting with a specific set of characters

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm using the RegExp below to find all links in a string. How to add a condition that *ignores* all links that start with one of these characters: `._ -`? (e.g.; `.sub.example.com`, `-example.com`)
AS3:

```
var str = "hello world .sub.example.com foo bar -example.com lorem http://example.com/test";  
var filter:RegExp = /((https?:\/\/|www\.)?[äöüa-z0-9]+[äöüa-z0-9\-\:\/]{1,}+\.[\*\!\'\(\)\;\:\@\&\=\$\,\?\#\%\[\]\~\-\+\_äöüa-z0-9\/\.]{2,}+)/gi

var links = str.match(filter)
if (links !== null) {
trace("Links: " + links);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
\b((https?:\/\/|www\.)?(?<![._ -])[äöüa-z0-9]+[äöüa-z0-9\-\:\/]{1,}+\.[\*\!\'\(\)\;\:\@\&\=\$\,\?\#\%\[\]\~\-\+\_äöüa-z0-9\/\.]{2,}+)\b
```

Edits:

- Added word boundaries `\b`
- Added negative look behind for `[._ -]` i.e.. `(?<![._ -])`

Comment: I tried the RegExp in AS3 but it's not valid. It seems that the brackets [] are the problem. Do I need to escape them or something?

Comment: No.. i dont think brackets are creating the problem.. negative lookbehinds are supported in AS3?

Comment: I don't know if they are supported. Is there an alternative I could try?

Comment: also.. what do you mean by not valid? are you getting any exception?

Comment: Are you using Flash? If you enter your RegExp in the IDE it will show in black instead of green - that means it's not valid. Also if I run it the RegExp isn't working correctly (links are not found) but there are no errors or something else.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex I use to find in full text :

```
/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i
```

---

Regex explanation:

```
\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]

Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(https?|ftp|file)»
   Match this alternative «https?»
      Match the character string “http” literally «http»
      Match the character “s” literally «s?»
         Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Or match this alternative «ftp»
      Match the character string “ftp” literally «ftp»
   Or match this alternative «file»
      Match the character string “file” literally «file»
Match the character string “://” literally «://»
Match a single character present in the list below «[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   The literal character “-” «-»
   A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
   A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
   A single character from the list “+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;” «+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;»
Match a single character present in the list below «[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]»
   A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
   A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
   A single character from the list “+&@#/%=~_|$” «+&@#/%=~_|$»
```